# Getting Started with RInside C++

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rinside

I've been an R user for about 4 years and over the past two weeks I've been developing a simple package of functions which analyse some data and plot some graphs in a way suitable for a project other members of my team and supervisor are working on and some upcoming ones too. So they've asked now if I can make it an executable file independent of the person having to know R - so it's a single .exe file with either text based menus or a simple gui.

I've been learning C++ slowly since winter and I figure RInside would be the best way to do this; use C++ to generate a .exe with R at it's heart for the amazing plotting and graphics, but it will be inside a executable my team can use. I have currently covered in C++ Variables, basic I/O with iostream, boolean and flow of control, functions, Arrays, Structures & Classes, Overloading Friends and References. I've had a look at Dirk's blog, and I have reinstalled R to C:\R\ and I have CodeBlocks and MinGW installed I've been learning C++ with. I need advice as to what precautions I should take and what things I should check/read/know before proceeding, and perhaps an advisable newb friendly way to start wading in and trying things.

Googling I find very little in the way of a tutorial or walk-through unlike Rcpp where people (for example like Hadley) have written awesome wiki's or blog-posts which I find a bit easier than jumping into the more technical documentation.

Comment: I believe this question would be more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Instead, you should ask your colleagues to spend 10 minutes learning how to type function names and arguments into the `R` command line!

Comment: Can't you distribute your application as an R script (an executable text file, with R code in it, starting with `#!/usr/bin/rscript`, that can be run independently)? This assumes that R is installed but, for the end-user, it is indistinguishable from a compiled executable.

Comment: As it stands it's an R package binary and the people who are using it presently contact me if they hit any trouble or send the data to me. But I think the real reason they're asking for an .exe is it's going to incorporate some other analyses (not necessarily R) as well from other related projects to form something big enough to make it worth combining together into an .exe, and they want my R code to be part of it. It's just as it stands my R stuff is one of the fist things to go into the .exe so I've been asked to have a go at sorting it.

Comment: Not what you asked for, but an alternative approach that I've used with great success is to create a GUI in R using the `gWidgets` package.  It's easy to learn, and simple GUIs can be created quickly.

Comment: M. Kraetzig tried something quite interesting with http://www.jstatcom.com/ that would create a GUI in java to communicate with the underlying R functions. There is an example of some time series procedures in JmultiR.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Question is a little unfocused but valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no walkthrough or tutorial -- because there are *six* example directories with a large number of examples.

Look at the ones in the `standard/` directory, which should take you from very simple to more advanced.

Here is for example the simplest hello-world example, `rinside_sample0.cpp`:

```
#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance 
    R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";       // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'
    R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)");           // eval init string, ignoring returns
    exit(0);
}
```

Just say 'make rinside_sample0' (or `make -f Makefile.win rinside_sample0` on Windows).  (Note that on Windows you need to get several DLLSs into your path etc pp -- Linux is easier that way._

Also look at earlier questions here in the `[rinside]` tag.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I'll have a play about and see what I can do - I have a linux partition on this PC too so if I struggle with Windows I can just switch.

Comment: Good idea! Many people use it on Windows, and I do test from time to time but I do find it more tedious.  For simple "existence proofs" Linux ought to be easier.  And please consider accepting / upvoting the answer as that is how the site works...